# Why patcher is not working?

Tags: c#

I tried to do an application, that can do auto updates. But it's not working.

Code of the main "Patched" app:

```
private void Patch()
{
        using (WebClient client = new WebClient())
        {
            string name = "asd681648.txt";
            client.DownloadFile("http://mypage/patches/" + "Graph" + ".txt", @"C:\" + name);
            string text = File.ReadAllText(@"C:\" + name);
            File.Delete(@"C:\" + name);
            string[] version = text.Split('.');
            string[] sVersion = set.ver.Split('.');
            for (int i = 0; i < version.Length; i++)
            {
                if (int.Parse(version[i]) > int.Parse(sVersion[i]))
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("New version will be downloaded!");
                    Process.Start(Environment.CurrentDirectory + "\\Patcher.exe", "Graph "+set.ver+" "+Environment.CurrentDirectory+"\\");
                    Application.Exit();
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
}
```

And the code of "Patcher":

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.Deployment.Compression.Cab;

namespace Patcher
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            WebClient client=new WebClient();
            string name = "asd2341648.txt";
            client.DownloadFile("http://mypage/patches/"+args[0]+".txt", @"C:\"+name);
            string text = File.ReadAllText(@"C:\" + name);
            File.Delete(@"C:\"+name);
            string[] version = text.Split('.');
            string[] sVersion = args[1].Split('.');
            for (int i = 0; i < version.Length; i++)
            {
                if(int.Parse(version[i])>int.Parse(sVersion[i]))
                {
                    break;
                }
                if(i==version.Length-1)
                {
                    return;
                }
            }
            Console.WriteLine("New version is avaliable. Downloading...");
            client.DownloadFile("http://mypage/patches/patches/" + args[0]+".cab",       @"C:\"+args[0]+".cab");
            CabInfo cab=new CabInfo(@"C:\"+args[0]+".cab");
            cab.Unpack(args[2]);
            File.Delete( @"C:\"+args[0]+".cab");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What's the problem? Is the method returning an error?

Comment: "it's not working" is not very well defined behavior. Please add comments on what it means in your case.

Comment: I started application and nothing happened. Yes, I updated the version on my page and set the version of application smaller, but still nothing happened.

Comment: You might want to add tracing to find out what is and isn't running.  Without providing information like that, no one is going to be able to help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can modify with (Delete txt extension from your first argument)

```
var path = Path.Combine("C:\",name);
client.DownloadFile("http://mypage/patches/"+args[0], @path);
```

You can modify also

```
 var path = Path.Combine("C:\",name);
 client.DownloadFile("http://mypage/patches/", @path);
```

You must set just adress of your file

```
public void DownloadFile(
    string address,
    string fileName
)
```

Link : http://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/vstudio/ez801hhe.aspx

Comment: Yeah, I'm going to try it :).

Comment: Sry It's the same problem :(.